# How to bind a TextField to an IBOutlet()?

Tags: python, cocoa, binding, pyobjc

I'm trying to figure out how to update an NSTextField programatically.

I've figured out how to get the current value of the Text Field from Python:

```
myVar = objc.IBOutlet()
....
self.myVar.stringValue()
```

How do I set the value of myVar from the Python side and have the GUI update?  I'd like some sort of two way binding (like {myVAR} in Flex).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I set the value of myVar from the Python side and have the GUI update?

Why would you want to? The nib loader set it to a control; if you set the variable, you would lose the control.

To set the value of the control, send it a `setStringValue_` (or similar) message.